# Android : list directory files

Tags: android

I try to list the files in a folder. While this folder contains files, I end up with a file array null.

Here's the code:

```
File dir =  Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
if (dir.isDirectory()) {   
    File[] files = dir.listFiles(); // files = null...
    for (File file : files) {
       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, file.getName(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
    }
}
```

I have the following path for dir: `"/storage/1CE3-110D/Pictures"`

[See for yourself the folder contents](http://prnt.sc/azwnz1)

I also try with another directory `(DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)` and another writing `(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory (), "Pictures")` without success.

I also have in my manifest :

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Thank you for your clarification!

Comment: Have you added the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission?

Comment: you may want to check the actual value of `dir`. is it really what you think it is?

Comment: Yes I had :    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />